# "Wrapping" a C char array by putting in '\n' every x characters -- Issue with strcat

Tags: c, string, strcat

I have a snippet of C code:

I want to add a new line character at certain intervals. The problem is, when I add it in the `if` block, on the next iteration, `strcat` takes it away, then concats `s` on, and then puts the `\n` at the end.

I can think of any other way to do this so `strcat` does not remove the `\n` that I want to add.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is curPos? What is s? How large is ans? A *compilable* example would be nice.

Comment: OK, I just put in my whole method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hmm... if curPos points to the the next available position in the array, than I would do this.  curPos + 1 points after the current '\0' termination of ans, since arrays in C are indexed starting at 0.

```
   if (i % 8 == 0 && i != 0)
   {
      ans[curPos++] = '\n';
      ans[curPos] = '\0'; /* always null terminate a string after any extension */      
   }
```

Comment: Hmm, I'm trying to see why this will work? Can you expand on this? BTW, I updated the code to include my full method.

Comment: Ok, i think your issue is that you need to set the first character in ans() equal to '\0', since the memory returned by malloc can be random values.  on the very first call to strcat(ans, s) where is the end of the string in ans?

Comment: I don't believe that is the issue. The issue (as far as I understand) is that `strcat` always removes the `'\n'` at the end of `ans` so when I add the new `\n` when the if block executes to true, that `\n` I just added is removed from `strcat`. This is from a C reference: "The terminating null character in destination is overwritten by the first character of source, and a null-character is included at the end of the new string formed by the concatenation of both in destination."

Comment: '\n' is not the null character '\0' is the null character. :-)  the only way for your logic to work is if curPos is always that the end of the ans string everytime you enter your block of code to add the '\n'.  If it is not.  on each call to strcat(ans, s).  strcat will start and ans[0], scan forword looking for ans[i] = '\0' and start adding s at the ans[i] position. if j = i + strlen(s). than ans after the return from strcat() will look like .....sssss'\0'

Comment: Mark, just got it! That was correct, I needed to set ans[curPos] to `\n` and ans[curPos + 1] to `\0`. Thank you! Also, I set `and[0] == '\0'`

Comment: Yes, when I was reading the documentation I was switching them in my head. After I replied with that comment I realized that! Thanks again!